# Accordion with floated divs

Tags: horizontal-accordion

My plan is to have some rows with 3 divs next to each other floated left replacing the Accordion-Headers, then open each div's content below a row of three pushing the rest of the page down.

I tried various 'position' possiblities but couldnt get it work the way I wanted it to.. 
More a css problem. Or better not use accordion?

jsfiddle.net/pCwxa/1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true },{ active: false });
  });
  </script>


<style type="text/css">

#link   {   background-color: grey;
    float: left; 
    height: 300px; 
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 20px 80px 0px;
    }

#cont   {   top:320px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 300px; 
    width: 880px;
    }           
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width:900px; height:900px; margin-left:30px; margin-bottom:; border:1px solid red;   padding:0px;">

<div id="accordion">
<div id="link">
<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3></div>
<div id="cont">
    <p>
    Blabla
</div>

<div id="link">
<h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3></div>
<div id="cont">
    <p>
    Blabla
    </p>
</div>

<div id="link"> 
<h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3></div>
<div id="cont">
    <p>
    Blabla
    </p>
</div>

<div id="link">

<h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3></div>
<div id="cont">
    <p>
    Blabla
    </p>
</div>
</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You state that there's a problem, but you don't describe what part of the behavior is not what you want. Also, it's much easier for someone to see what's happening if you use something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that people can see it with a single click.

Comment: I want the cont-div to open below the first 3 link-divs. Now it opens underneath it, if I use absolute position, it doesnt push down the rest of page. I'm very new to JS, and basic in CSS only so your help is appreciated! http://jsfiddle.net/pCwxa/1/

Comment: It would be useful for others to have the fiddle in the body of the question, near the top.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the `div` elements arranged in alternating order, with each `div.link` alternating with `div.cont`. Instead, put the three `div.link` first and then three `div.cont`. Use CSS `clear` to ensure that the second group of three appears on a new line.

Comment: Doesn't work. "The markup of your accordion container needs pairs of headers and content panels", so how can I connect these then?

Comment: Where's that quotation from?

Comment: Oh. Well, as usual, if a jQuery UI widget doesn't behave like you want, you frequently have to write a custom version. They tend not to have pluggable behavior, either. You need two modifications. (1) A way to associate the links with the content, if they're not contiguous. (2) Methods for expanding and collapsing content.